# Using Auto reset event is not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I am quite new to c# programming, I am trying to achieve the following result but failing to do so.

**What I expect -:**
On a click event of a button, I want to open an applciation via its API, run analysis and then exit the application. While running the application I have a progress bar on the form which should keep going from 0 - 100 till the `RunAnalysis()`  method called through the API gets executed, when it gets executed the progress bar should show as 100% and the application called through should exit

**What is happening -:**

The `RunanAlysis()` is being executed and the application exits, the click event of the button gets executed and then the progress bar moves from 0 - 100 which should not happen

**What is my attempt**

```
namespace trialapp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AutoResetEvent obj = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ETABS2015.cSapModel SapModel;
        System.Reflection.Assembly ETABSAssembly;
        ETABS2015.cOAPI ETABSObject;
        int result = -1;
        delegate int MyDelegate();
        MyDelegate pointer = null;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Use ret to check return values of OAPI calls 
            int ret;

            //Dynamically load ETABS.exe assembly from the program installation folder 
            string pathToETABS = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMFILES"), "Computers and Structures", "ETABS 2013", "ETABS.exe");
            ETABSAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToETABS);

            //Create an instance of ETABSObject and get a reference to cOAPI interface
            ETABSObject = (ETABS2015.cOAPI)ETABSAssembly.CreateInstance("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject");

            //Start ETABS application
            ret = ETABSObject.ApplicationStart();

            //Get a reference to cSapModel to access all OAPI classes and functions
            SapModel = ETABSObject.SapModel;

            //Initialize model
            ret = SapModel.InitializeNewModel();

            //Create steel deck template model
            ret = SapModel.File.NewSteelDeck(4, 12, 12, 4, 4, 24, 24);

            //Save model
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\ETABSAPI");
            ret = SapModel.File.Save("C:\\ETABSAPI\\example2.edb");

            //Run analysis
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
           // ret = SapModel.Analyze.RunAnalysis();


            obj.WaitOne();

            //Close ETABS
            ret = ETABSObject.ApplicationExit(false);

            //Clean up variables
            SapModel = null;
            ETABSObject = null;

            //Check ret value 
            if (ret == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("API script completed succesfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("API script FAILED to complete.");
            }

        }

        public void AfterRunAnalysisComplete(IAsyncResult resultHolder)
        {
            result = pointer.EndInvoke(resultHolder);

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            pointer = new MyDelegate(SapModel.Analyze.RunAnalysis);

            IAsyncResult flag = pointer.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(AfterRunAnalysisComplete), null);

            while (!flag.IsCompleted)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
                {

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                    if (i == 100)
                    {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    if (flag.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
            //obj.Set();


        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one tell me as to where exactly am I going wrong?

**Edit -:**

I tried not using `WaitOne()` and putting the code which follows`backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` in the `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method, but that is not I want to do as the extent of main project is too much and this will not make sense with the design of classes.

Comment: When you have a specific problem with your code, please create a minimal working example showing the problem. Problem is, when I read your code, I only can tell that it _looks_ ok. But that does not mean much. I cannot try out your code, since I don't classes you use in your reflection code or files on my hard-drive. As far as I can see, the `WaitOne()` should block forever since `Set()` is commented out.

Comment: I have already tried with set() but it didn't work. Also I wanted the question as clear as possible but I am not sure which part would be critical for the one who's looking into it.

Comment: Then, I'm very sorry but cannot help you.

Comment: So, when you had the Set() in place, it unblocked the caller and therefore exiting the app. From the code, this happens when the flag is set to complete so you need to find out...at what point the flag was set to complete which caused it to break from the while loop and call Set() which in turn exits the application. To me it works fine but it is your logic that maybe incorrect :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I see it, is when you kick off

```
ret = ETABSObject.ApplicationStart();
```

it's going to start it in a new thread, which your program isn't going to have access to. I would recommend starting the application in a TaskFactory, then you can use a while to check if the task is still running and update your progress bar.

Maybe something like this:

```
var etabApp = Task.Factory.Startnew(() => { ETABSObject.ApplicationStart()});

while(etabApp.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
{
   //Do something to check the percent complete and update the progress bar
}
```